# Connecting to multiple databases in Active Record

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord, castle-activerecord

I'm trying to connect to multiple databases in castle active record (which uses nhibernate.) My config file looks like this:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="activerecord" type="Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Config.ActiveRecordSectionHandler, Castle.ActiveRecord" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <activerecord>
    <config type="Navtrak.Business.Schemas.CommonSchemas.Models.NavtrakOperations.NavtrakOperationsDatabase`1, CommonSchemas">
      <add key="hibernate.connection.connection_string" value="myconnstring" />
      <add key="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" />
      <add key="hibernate.dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect" />
      <add key="hibernate.connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
    </config>
    <config type="Navtrak.Business.Schemas.CommonSchemas.Models.Errors.ErrorsDatabase`1, CommonSchemas">
      <add key="hibernate.connection.connection_string" value="Data Source=myconnstring" />
      <add key="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" />
      <add key="hibernate.dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect" />
      <add key="hibernate.connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
    </config>
  </activerecord>
```

And then I have a base abstract class for each database like this:

```
public abstract class NavtrakOperationsDatabase<T> : ActiveRecordBase<T>
    {

    }
```

And then each class inherits from this. I'm then initializing active record like this:

```
ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(typeof(SimpleModel).Assembly, ActiveRecordSectionHandler.Instance);
```

Which gives me the error:

**Could not find the dialect in the configuration**

If I change the activation code to this:

```
ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(
                    ActiveRecordSectionHandler.Instance,
                    typeof(NavtrakOperationsDatabase<>),
                    typeof(ErrorsDatabase<>)
                );
```

Then I get the following error:

**You have accessed an ActiveRecord class that wasn't properly initialized. There are two possible explanations: that the call to ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize() didn't include Navtrak.Business.Schemas.CommonSchemas.Models.NavtrakOperations.Application class, or that Navtrak.Business.Schemas.CommonSchemas.Models.NavtrakOperations.Application class is not decorated with the [ActiveRecord] attribute.**

I obviously don't want to include every single class in the Initialize function.

Any ideas?

Comment: what version of activerecord are you using?

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer - I'm using the latest dll's for .NET 4 (I think), as I downloaded them about a week ago.

Comment: @Justin - Could you update to show the final syntax of everything you used?  I'm trying the same thing, but can't get past the error you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the "hibernate." prefix from all config keys. That prefix was used in NHibernate 1.x

Answer (score 1):

In my case - which was the same situation - I have added this to the InitializeAR method:

```
LoggerProvider.SetLoggersFactory(new NoLoggingLoggerFactory());
```

It ended up like this:

```
lock (typeof(SessionManager))
{
    if (!initialized)
    {
        LoggerProvider.SetLoggersFactory(new NoLoggingLoggerFactory());                
        System.Reflection.Assembly bin = typeof(SimpleModel).Assembly;
        IConfigurationSource s = (IConfigurationSource)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("activerecord");
        ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(bin, s);

    }
    initialized = true;
}
```